# How do I find unsigned BB[] such that (char *) (BB + 1) = "Red Ross!"

Tags: c

I have this short code fragment:

```
 unsigned BB[] = ???; 
 printf("%s\n", (char *) (BB + 1));
```

I want the output of that printf to be "Red Ross!". I do not know how to approach this kind of problem, I think it has to do with ASCII table.

Here are some assumptions that can be used:

- 32-bit little-endian platform
- sizeof(char) == 1
- sizeof(unsigned) == 4

Comment: the first unsigned can be anything since it's discarded. Now try filling your table with `0x41424344` to try to see some chars apprearing. And yes, it makes an endian dependant code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Why should I try precisely 0x41424344 and not something else?

Comment: @LudovicoBessi Try it first and you will see (`BB[] = {0x41424300}`). Also please take time to observe ASCII table.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at which codes each letter corresponds to in the ASCII table might be helpful, but not necessary. You can assign character literals to an integer just fine, by using bitwise OR and bit shift:

```
uint32_t x = ('A' << 24) | ('B' << 16) | ('C' << 8) | 'D';
```

This puts `'A'` in the most significant  byte. Where that is depends on endianess. On little endian, the above would result in `"DCBA"`.

This should be enough to solve the assignment. Do remember that strings are null terminated, so you need to end the "string" with a zero.

Comment: As the only serious and good answer thus far, this needs an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking the target string and printing out the value of each byte:

```
char *str = "Red Ross!";
int i;
for (i=0; i<strlen(str); i++) {
    printf("%02x ", str[i]);
 }
```

This will tell you what values to use.  Then you can use those values to populate your `unsigned` array.

Because the `unsigned` values are implemented at 32-bit little endian, each element can store 4 bytes, and those bytes needs to be stored in the reverse order they should be displayed in due to little-endian byte ordering.

For example, if you wanted to store 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, and 0x04 in that order in a single `unsigned`, you would do so as follows:

```
unsigned value = 0x04030201;
```

So using those two pieces of information, you can construct your `unsigned` array.  Also, because you need to start with `BB + 1`, the value first element of the array doesn't matter.

Lastly, make sure the last element of the array is 0 so that your string is null terminated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, given that you've sacrificed a lot of portability already (around sizes of built-in types, complementing schemes, and endianness), why not go the whole hog and use *multicharacter constants* ?

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned BB[] = {[1] = ' deR', 'ssoR', '!'}; // little endian
    printf("%s\n", (char *) (BB + 1));
}
```

will do it, where I've made some fairly commonplace assumptions about your compiler's implementation of multicharacter constants. Note the use of the  *designated initialiser* `[1]`.

Saves all that fishing around in your character tables.

Working example at https://ideone.com/9DiFgy

Comment: Err... multi-character constants? Also the proper use of designated initializers would be `[1] =`, everything else I believe is some pre-standard gcc junk.

Comment: @Lundin: You're correct naturally, especially on the `=` point, which I've corrected along with yet more sloppy terminology from me. I quite like the multicharacter constant approach though, especially that this is more of a fun rather than serious question.